# Remove build from PR in Bitbucket using API

Tags: merge, bitbucket, commit, bamboo

i have a project with two submodules - one is for the source code(A) and the second one contains end to end tests(B). The problem is that the build of the source code is successful, but e2e tests are failing and this does not allow me to merge. Is there any way bitbucket to get result only from A submodule and to skip the result from submodule B? Is there any way to say which result to be used as validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can disable the e2e test from your plan spec file. Or you can disable the test scan from the UI as well from under the tasks tab in the job stage. But it would be good to investigate why your tests are failing.

Comment: i found a solution. I just removed the linked repositories and now repo and the tests are not connected

Comment: great @BozhidarMarinov